# Securing files in non-web location accessed via symlink

Tags: php, apache, permissions

So I have a PHP application. The permissions are set to appropriate ones for www-data user and group. The problem is that I have files being generated by another server process (a java process) running under a different user that PHP needs to access. They are also in another directory not registered with the vhost.

So I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I think I can create a symlink to that directory in my php folder that's already accessible via the virtualhost (checking to make sure apache is following symlinks). So then I will still have to change the permissions on the actual files, right--maybe add www-data to the group that creates those files? Does that mean www-data would potentially have access to all the files owned by that group? Are the apache directory permissions enough to prevent a potential attacker from moving outside the directory with those specific files I want served?

Alternatively I could create a new virtualhost that runs under the user that owns those files, and just access the files via a different subdomain.

I could potentially see about creating the files as owned by the www-data group and having group read permissions on the files.

Anyway, just seeing whether there's a standard best practice for this issue.

Comment: Try it.  There's no need for the files to be owned by 'www-data', I'd suggest having them owned by another user.  You just want Php to be able to read them.  Writing to the file system is where it gets a little more interesting.  Are you using Php-fpm or mod_php?

Comment: Anyhow, you'll want to add a few examples here.  Write down your attempts and where you stumble, else your question will likely be closed.